# Pilot age limit to serve as required crew on an FAR 135 flight into Mexico?

Tags: crew

Curious to know if Mexico has filed a difference to the ICAO Annex 1 limitation of age 65, which would permit pilots over age 65 to operate a commercial flight into Mexico.